# Group data on a single column and merge another column

Tags: c#, linq

I have a set of objects that have the following columns

```
Id
ShiftStart
ShiftEnd
```

An example set of data

```
Id  ShiftStart  ShiftEnd
1   8.30        12.00
1   13.30       15.00
2   8.30        12.00
2   13.30       15.00
3   8.30        12.00
```

What I want to achieve is,

select all items with matching id and then merge the shift data. Separated by a comma

So an example final object would contain the following data

```
Id  ShiftStart    ShiftEnd
1   8.30, 13.30   12.00, 15.00    
2   8.30, 13.30   12.00, 15.00
3   8.30          12.00
```

Comment: [`Enumerable.GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TResult> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>, Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by the Id, then join together all times within each group:

```
var groupedData
  = yourList.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
            .Select(g => new { Id = g.Key,
                               ShiftStartTimes = string.Join(", ", g.Select(x => x.ShiftStart))
                               ShiftEndTimes = string.Join(", ", g.Select(x => x.ShiftEnd)) });
```

Query syntax:

```
var groupedData =
    from x in yourList
    group x by x.Id into g
    select new {
       Id = g.Key,
       ShiftStartTimes = String.Join(", ", g.Select(x => x.ShiftStart)),
       ShiftEndTimes = String.Join(", ", g.Select(x => x.ShiftEnd))
   };
```

Comment: I added also query syntax, which I find more readable in this case

Comment: There is an [overload of `GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx) that obviates the need for a separate `Select`.